# ValueError when overriding the choices for a ForeignKey field in a model's admin

Tags: django, forms, admin

I'm overriding the admin form of a model to modify the `choices` of a `ForeignKey` field.
When selecting a choice in the admin form, and saving, I get a `ValueError`:

```
Cannot assign "u'6'": "MyModel1.mymodel2" must be a "MyModel2" instance
```

where `6` is the id of the selected choice.

The new `choices` is built as `((<choice_1_id>, <choice_1_label>), (<choice_2_id>, <choice_2_label>),...)`, and I get the same html for the rendered select widget as if I don't modify the `choices` (apart from the ordering of course).

If I comment `self.fields['mymodel2'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices)` in `MyModel1AdminForm.__init__()` I get no error...

Anybody could help?

**models.py**

```
class MyModel1(models.Model):
    mymodel2 = ForeignKey(MyModel2)
    # more fields...
```

**admin.py**

```
class MyModel1AdminForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel1

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs): 
        super(MyModel1AdminForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        # create choices with ((<choice_1_id>, <choice_1_label>), (<choice_2_id>, <choice_2_label>),...)

        self.fields['mymodel2'] = forms.ChoiceField(choices=choices, widget=SelectWithDisabled) # http://djangosnippets.org/snippets/2453/


class MyModel1Admin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyModel1AdminForm
my_site.register(MyModel1, MyModel1Admin)
```

Answer (score 1):

`mymodel2` is the Foreign Key field. You need to supply the queryset if you want to change the choices instead of adding your custom choices:

```
self.fields['mymodel2'].queryset = MyModel2.objects.all()
```

Comment: I actually need to modify the choices because I want to disable some options (I'm using a custom Select widget). I updated my question to add the widget to the forms.ChoiceField.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to construct the choices manually something like

```
choices = MyModel2.objects.values_list('pk', 'title')
```

should work with a standard `ChoiceField`, where `title` is the field of the model you want to use as label/verbose name for your choice.

---

Looking at the snippet you are using `values_list` won't work so you could fallback to a list comprehension:

```
[(c.pk, {'label': c.title, 'disabled': False}) for c in MyModel2.objects.all()]
```

Though you obviously need some more logic to decide whether a choice is enabled or disabled.

Comment: I get the same ValueError error when saving. It seems that I should use a forms.ModelChoiceField, but then I can only set a queryset, not choices.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up overriding `ModelChoiceField`:

```
class MyModelChoiceField(forms.ModelChoiceField):
    def label_from_instance(self, obj):
        level = getattr(obj, obj._mptt_meta.level_attr)
        return {'label': obj.name), 'disabled': check_disabled(obj)}
```